# draw stack chart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I want to draw a stack chart in R : 
My data set is as follows called df:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("A","B"),
                   x1 = c(10,30),
                   x2 = c(20,40),
                   x3 = c(70,30)), row.names = 1:2,
                   class = "data.frame")

    df<- melt(df, id.vars = "id")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill =id)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("\nCategory") +
  ylab("Percentage\n") +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

The out put is not the one that I want,

> I want to to see id in the x axis and x1,x2,x3 in the stacked column.

Comment: Try changing your `aes()` parameter from `aes(x = variable, y = value, fill =id)` to `aes(x = id, y = value, fill =variable)`

Comment: YesI found the answer thank you so much.

Comment: Could you please let me know why on the y axis only it shows up to 70% not all the range ?

Answer (score 4):

ggplot's `x` always specifies the x-axis, `fill` the variable you want to categorize your data by. So to create your desired plot, the code is:

```
    library(reshape2) ## for melt()
    library(ggplot2)

    df<- melt(n_df, id.vars = "id")

    ggplot(data = n_df, aes(x = id, y = value, fill =variable)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      xlab("\nCategory") +
      ylab("Percentage\n") +
      guides(fill = FALSE) +
      theme_bw()
```

[image: Output:]

If you want to have the legend show up, you have to `guides(fill = TRUE)` :

[image: Second Plot]

Comment: How can I add the x1,x2and x3 in the graph?and when I try to draw it only shows unto 70 percentage in the y axis?

Comment: @user46759 edited my answer. The 70%-thing seems odd, I used your code exactly. Maybe try restarting RStudio?